# Typoscript - Use regex replace on field value

Tags: regex, typo3, typoscript

A part of a COA I have gets the page title. What I would like to do is replace the space between the last two words with a `&nbsp;`

But adding the stdWrap.replacement part results in no output at all:

```
stdWrap.cObject = COA
stdWrap.cObject {
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = title
  10.htmlSpecialChars = 1
  10.wrap = <h2>|</h2>
  10.stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
      search = \s(\S+)$
      replace = &nbsp;\1
      useRegExp = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with delimiters - `/\s(\S+)$/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked, thank you. You should add as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Typo3 `replacement` docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement/Index.html#replacement):

```
10 {
  search = #(a )CAT#i
  replace = \1cat
  useRegExp = 1
}
```

The `#` in `#(a )CAT#i` are [*regex delimiters*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). So, all you need is provide any, say:

```
search = /\s(\S+)$/
```